# viewDidAppear called before applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm just starting an iphone app with a initial `viewcontroller` which is embeded in a `navigationController` and have a `pushSegue` to a `tabBarController`.

Whenever I run the simulator,  viewDidAppear of the initial `viewController` called before `applicationDidBecomeActive` being called.

Isn't it suppose to enter `applicationDidBecomeActive` in `appdelegate` before any `viewController` load?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS8, viewDidLoad used to run before applicationDidBecomeActive. However, in iOS9, I'm seeing that with the same code, applicationDidBecomeActive is running before viewDidLoad. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's ok I think you are just little confuse. How an application will become active until it's load it's view.

When you first time launch the application will call the method in order -

From App Delegate -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

From View Controller -

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

- (void)viewDidLoad

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

From App Delegate -

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application is called before - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated, not after.

Comment: @russell have you checked or commenting upon your concept??

Comment: I created a test project and checked on iOS 6, 7, and 8. In iOS 8, viewDidAppear: is called before applicationDidBecomeActive:. In iOS 6 and 7, applicationDidBecomeActive: is called before viewDidAppear:. However, in my real app project, applicationDidBecomeActive: is called before viewDidAppear: even on iOS 8. I guess the order depends on the iOS version and some other conditions... Do you have any thoughts on this? Thanks.

Comment: I tested this too - it varies based on OS. In iOS8, viewDidLoad used to run before applicationDidBecomeActive. However, in iOS9, I'm seeing that with the same code, applicationDidBecomeActive is running before viewDidLoad. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

`applicationDidBecomeActive` is a delegate located in your Application Delegate and there's no guarantee that it will be called before any other UIViewController delegates (viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad etc.). If you want to make any logic before loading of any other view controller method is called, you may want to use `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.